# Функция php не видит глобальную переменную

Tags: php

Подключаюсь к БД, в самом начале документа. После вызываю метод, где создается запрос к пунктам меню

```
    public $db;

    public function __construct(){
        $db = mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DB)
                or die("Ошибка соединения с базой данных");
    }

    public function menu_array(){   
        $query = "SELECT id_menu, name_menu FROM menu";

        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die("Ошибка запроса к таблице - menu");

        $row = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < mysql_num_rows($result); $i++) { 
            $row[] = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
        }

        return $row;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Доброго дня!

Судя по всему это класс. А в классе обращаться к такой переменной следует через `$this`, т.е. `$this->db`

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query) or die("Ошибка запроса к таблице - menu");

Не работает

Comment: А обращение в конструкторе к переменной вы исправили? должно быть `$this->db = mysqli_connect(...`